# Is possible to trigger context.js context menu on mouse left click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have context menu in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application. I implement a context menu using `context.js`.

Every thing works fine.

[image]

But i need to trigger this context menu on left click. is there any

option to change trigger position in `context.js`. I already found many other context menus

with this left trigger option. But all the context menus are different style from  bootstrap.

So i need to add this options in this `context.js`. Or If any other bootstrap supported

context menu exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

**[jQuery context menu plugin](http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/)**

This plugin can be used for **left click** as well.